# Which p-adic algebraic groups are type I?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, oa.operator-algebras

It was proved by Jacques Dixmier (Sur les représentations unitaires des groupes de Lie algébriques, Annales de l'institut Fourier, 7 (1957), p. 315-328, doi: [10.5802/aif.73](https://doi.org/10.5802/aif.73), [MR 20 #5820](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=20:5820), [Zbl 0080.32101](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0080.32101))

that algebraic groups over the reals, are type I. Is a similar result known for algebraic groups over non-archimedean local fields (possibly of characteristic 0)? I am only aware of the result by Bernstein

[http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Publication_list/publication_texts/bernstein-P-tame-FAN.pdf](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Ebernstei/Publication_list/publication_texts/bernstein-P-tame-FAN.pdf)

that reductive algebraic groups over non-archimedean local fields, are type I.

Comment: Your first link doesn't work for me:(

Comment: @Marc: Yes there is something weird with the link, that I couldn't fix. I put the reference instead. 

Comment: http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIF/AIF_1957__7_/AIF_1957__7__315_0/AIF_1957__7__315_0.pdf

Comment: Or for those not able to speak french: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=ALLF&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=dixmier&s5=Lie&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=30&mx-pid=99380

Comment: To add a further link for those wanting Bernstein's note in the original Russian: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=faa&paperid=2324&option_lang=eng

Comment: @Alain: Note that Joseph Bernstein's name has an extra "n", though there is also a mathematician named Berstein.   (To add to the name confusion, early English translations of Russian papers co-authored by Joseph Bernstein gave his initials as I.N.)

Comment: Thanks to David for reviving my question of 2 years ago. My reason for asking was a computation (joint with Henrik Petersen) of $L^2$-Betti numbers for locally compact groups, valid under a type I assumption; see
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0379.pdf

Comment: @AlainValette: Dear Alain, why Thm 1 in "All reductive p-adic groups are tame" by Bernshtein implies that reductive algebraic groups over non-archimedean local fields, are type I? or do you have a reference for this?

Answer (score 14):

Duflo gave a classification of the irreducible unitary representations of any algebraic group over a characteristic zero local field, in terms of the answer in the reductive case (Duflo, Michel Théorie de Mackey pour les groupes de Lie algébriques. (French) [Mackey theory for algebraic Lie groups] Acta Math. 149 (1982), no. 3-4, 153–213.) My guess would be that the type I result in general follows from Bernstein's type I result in the reductive case by Duflo's classification; but I don't know that for certain, and Duflo does not state such a result.

Comment: The first question would be whether unipotent $p$-adic groups are all of type I.

Comment: @YCor: The answer is yes.  unipotent p -adic groups are all CCR, in particular type I. See Theorem 4 "Decomposition of Unitary Representations Defined by Discrete Subgroups of Nilpotent Groups" by Calvin C. Moore
http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970567?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 5):

Theorem 1.2.3 (p18) of

MOHAMED HACHMI SLIMAN
Théorie de Mackey pour les groupes adéliques
Astérisque, tome 115 (1984) [Link at SMF site](https://smf.emath.fr/download/pdf/107560)

asserts that the $F$-points of linear algebraic groups over characteristic zero local fields $F$ are of type 1.  The author states the result in a slightly more general setting that allows for some covering groups.

Comment: This is far from holding in such a setting. In this theorem there are many assumptions on the field and on the algebraic group which you're omitting.

Comment: I am confused by this.  In the original question the field is local so I didn't say that explicitly before.  I don't see how you can't recover the statement I gave above by taking $G=G(F)$, $F=1$, and $\underline{\underline{G}}=G$ in the notation of the reference.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Indeed I had the impression that more hypotheses were missing, but it seems indeed to hold in this setting (and "local field" in this book means "nondiscrete locally compact field").